# Keep record of previously visited states when searching

Tags: haskell, search, functional-programming

I am programming several search functions, for which I use the `Node` datatype:

```
data Node a =
  Node { [...]
       , getPath :: [a]    -- ^ Previous states this node has visited
       }
```

That field, `getPath`, is what I use to check if I have previously visited that state in that node: when expanding a new node, I check that by doing:

```
visited = `elem` path
```

It works, but it becomes incredibly costly when there are a lot of nodes expanded and the paths become too long. Is there a better way to keep track of the states I have visited? Maybe a different data structure (instead of a list) that performs better for this use?

Comment: If `a` is *hashable*, you can use a *hashset*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what constraints your elements have (or can be given).

If your elements have an `Ord` constraint then you can use [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html) from containers to get `O(log n)` membership tests.

If your elements have a `Hashable` constraint then you can use a [`HashSet`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.19/unordered-containers-0.2.8.0/Data-HashSet.html#t:HashSet) from unordered-containers to get `O(log n)` membership tests with better constant factors* and a large enough base that they are effectively constant time for most use cases.

If your elements only have an `Eq` constraint then you can't do better than a list.

---

* Depending on the performance of the `Hashable` instance. When in doubt, benchmark.