# Checking Haskell typeclasses in a function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

If I wanted to perform a search on a problem space and I wanted to keep track of different states a node has already visited, I [several options to do it depending on the constraints of those states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636042/keep-record-of-previously-visited-states-when-searching). However; is there a way I can dispatch a function or another depending on the constraint of the states the user is using as input? For example, if I had:

```
data Node a = Node { state :: a, cost :: Double }
```

And I wanted to perform a search on a `Problem a`, is there a way I could check if `a` is `Eq`, `Ord` or `Hashable` and then call a different kind of search? In pseudocode, something like:

```
search :: Eq a => Problem a -> Node a
search problem@(... initial ...) -- Where initial is a State of type a
  | (Hashable initial) = searchHash problem
  | (Ord initial)      = searchOrd problem
  | otherwise          = searchEq problem
```

I am aware I could just let the user choose one `search` or another depending on their own use; but being able to do something like that could be very handy for me since search is not really one of the user endpoints as such (one example could be a function `bfs`, that calls `search` with some parameters to make it behave like a Breadth-First Search).

Comment: All type information is erased during compilation: at runtime, values are not tagged in memory with their types, nor there is a representation of all the typeclass instances. This makes such checks impossible. If this information is needed, then the programmer must explicitly ask to keep it around, e.g. like Daniel Wagner does below with a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. However, you could make your own class:

```
class Memorable a where
    type Memory a
    remember :: a -> Memory a -> Memory a
    known :: a -> Memory a -> Bool
```

Instantiate this class for a few base types, and add some default implementations for folks that want to add new instances, e.g.

```
-- suitable implementations of Memorable methods and type families for hashable things
type HashMemory = Data.HashSet.HashSet
hashRemember = Data.HashSet.insert
hashKnown = Data.HashSet.member

-- suitable implementations for orderable things
type OrdMemory = Data.Set.Set
ordRemember = Data.Set.insert
ordKnown = Data.Set.member

-- suitable implementations for merely equatable things
type EqMemory = Prelude.[]
eqRemember = (Prelude.:)
eqKnown = Prelude.elem
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it: I still don't know how to make an implementation of the  `Memorable` class of something as `Eq a`, which would let me generalize it. Is something like `instance Memorable (Eq a => a) where` possible?

Comment: @DiegoVicente If that were possible, you wouldn't need the `Memorable` type class. `Eq` simply does not carry enough information to perform the checks you want.

Comment: @DiegoVicente No, that's not possible (well, it is; but then you can't have any other instances). You have to write e.g. `instance Memorable Int where type Memory Int = EqMemory Int; remember = eqRemember; known = eqKnown` if you want `Int` to use the `Eq` instance for its memory. Yes, this means you have to duplicate all the instance declarations that already exist for `Ord`, `Hashable`, and `Eq` -- and this is why most people just pick either `Ord` or `Hashable` and run with it.

Comment: @DanielWagner oh, ok, now I get it! I thought it was a different workaround, didn't get the point at first. I think I'll then stick to the `Hashable` type, thank you!